# Pointer to pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I hope you can help me.

I have a function in c, which takes a file, reads line for line and stores every line as a string. It works in this function

```
int createDownloadList(FILE **dllistref, dltask* taskList) {
    ...
    taskList = (dltask*) malloc(tasksize*allocsize);
    int num = 0;
    while(getline(&line, &linesize, *dllistref) > 0) {
        ...
        taskList[num] = task;
        num++;
        if(num%8 == 0) {
            taskList = realloc(taskList, (num+allocsize)*tasksize);
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

But I want to access the pointer to the taskList outside of the function. I tried it with this change

```
int createDownloadList(FILE **dllistref, dltask** taskList) {
    size_t linesize = 256;
    char* line = (char*) malloc(linesize);
    size_t tasksize = sizeof(dltask);
    int allocsize = 8;
    *taskList = (dltask*) malloc(tasksize*allocsize);
    int num = 0;

    while(getline(&line, &linesize, *dllistref) > 0) {
        ...
        *taskList[num] = task;
        num++;
        if(num%8 == 0) {
            *taskList = realloc(taskList, (num+allocsize)*tasksize);
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

But I get always a segmentation fault after the third task and don't know why. I hope someone can help me, I am clueless, why it won't work.
Oh, and that's how I call the second function in the main method:

```
dltask* taskList = NULL;
numOfTasks = createDownloadList(&fileref_dllist, &taskList)
```

I only added the "&" in the call, otherwise it's the same call for the first function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `realloc(taskList, (num+allocsize)*tasksize);` --> `realloc(*taskList, (num+allocsize)*tasksize);`

Comment: the call to `realloc()` can fail.  When it fails, the `*tasklist` will contain NULL, so the pointer to the already allocated memory is overlayed, lost.  This means the pointer cannot be passed to `free()`.  this results in a memory leak.   When calling `realloc()`, always use a temporary/local variable, then check (!=NULL) the temporary variable before making the assignment to the `*tasklist` variable.

Comment: regarding the parameter: `dllistref`  why pass the address of that pointer?  the function is not changing that pointer.  So just pass the pointer, then the signature of the function becomes: `int createDownloadList(FILE *dllistref, dltask** taskList)` and the call to it becomes: `int createDownloadList(dllistref, &taskList)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line

```
*taskList = realloc(taskList, (num+allocsize)*tasksize);
```

have to be

```
*taskList = realloc(*taskList, (num+allocsize)*tasksize);
```

**EDIT**

The second error, found out by @user3121023, is:

```
*taskList[num] = task;
```

that should be

```
(*taskList)[num] = task;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it makes no difference. Same segmentation fault after the third element :(

Comment: @mKay We haven't got your real code. I cannot see other errors. Is `tasksize*allocsize` at least `8` element?

Comment: yes, I can copy the code if you want, but I thought there couldn't be a mistake, because the first function works, same size, same everything and all I changed was the pointer of taskList. But I'll edit it in my question.

Comment: @user3121023 Yes, it is. Good catch.